# SQL query in PowerPivot import with word "flag" as column alias breaks workbook

Tags: sql, excel, powerpivot, corruption

One of my peers had an Excel workbook break, making it so he wasn't able to open the PowerPivot part of the file any longer.  After many hours of trial and error he discovered that the problem was being caused because he had aliased a column in one of his Teradata SQL queries to include the word "flag."

We had several users create dummy workbooks and attempt to replicate this error.  Every user received the same error.  After creating a basic table using a SQL import from Teradata with a single column aliased as "flag" or any alias that contained that string of characters, the users are unable to save the workbook.

I looked all over Google, but I couldn't find anything in reference to this or perhaps reserved words that aren't allowed in a SQL import to PowerPivot.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: Did they test aliasing columns without using "flag"?